# OrientDb - Conducting a query

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-2.1

I have DB with following schema
[image]

I want to conduct a query to find all the vertexes which have only 'A' and dont't have 'B' as their descendant (c.out('RepositoryEdge').out('InfoEdge')) 
For Specific example only vertex #33:53 satisfies this condion

How Should i Conduct My Query ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select from <class-name> where @rid not in (select in("InfoEdge").in("RepositoryEdge") from #42:0) and @rid in (select in("InfoEdge").in("RepositoryEdge") from #41:5)
```

Hope it helps

Regards